# Селектор времени на android только для минут, как добавить?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Хочу добавить в приложение селектор времени в виде барабана или часов (см.фото). Но важно, чтобы они были только для минут. Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [`NumberPicker`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html). Это стандартный класс в Android SDK. При помощи него и реализованы все это `DatePicker`'ы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]